# SlowCheetah not working after installation of azure sdk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project, slowcheetah, azure-sdk-.net

I have Visual Studio 2010 together with slowcheetah. I have a website where I use multiple configuration files and some of them need to have different values on debug and on release. To accomplish this I use slowcheetah and every time I publish the website using the Release option my configs get transformed normally.

After I installed Azure SDK, the website VS2010 publish interface changed. Now when I publish using VS the configuration files don't transform. If I publish through command line using msbuild, they get changed.

Is there a way to make the configuration transformation with slowcheetah working toghether with azure sdk and VS2010 publish?

Comment: have you even read my question ?

Comment: Sorry, I must have made comment at the wrong place ;p

Comment: I've submitted a bug to the Slow Cheetah github page. Hopefully we get a resolution soon. https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just commented back on the [issue](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/19) but I pasted the content below for those who may find this here. Let me know if you still have problems after trying the new VSIX.

This should be resolved by commit c6e4a4c.
I have an updated download available at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40134810/SlowCheetah-c6e4a4c.zip I'd appreciate it if you could verify the fix. For now I will close this item but please re-open if it you are still seeing an issue after installing that update.

I will update the public release probably in a week or so. I have a few more bugs which need to be fixed.

if you'd like to try it out.

Comment: The bug is fixed in SlowCheetah 2.4.1

Comment: Running 2.5 and transforms are being ignored when packaging/ publishing an Azure Cloud Service.
Build Configuration in VS and setting for the Cloud Project both set to Release. In the service project (not the azure project) the build/ release directory is actually converted properly. However, the csx/Release directory ends up with the debug configuration without transformation.

Comment: I haven't implemented the Azure support yet. There is an open issue on the github page. This question states that normal SlowCheetah web scenarios break after installing the Azure SDK.